# MySQL query crashes when ORDER BY is added, works fine otherwise

Tags: mysql, join, crash, sql-order-by

I am working on a database with several thousands of entries, for this particular query I want some operations to be performed with the data and then get the results ordered by a column. The ORDER BY clause causes the database manager to take forever to load and eventually it crashes without retrieving any results, it works fine otherwise.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT m.*,
timediff(n.hora_origen,m.hora_destino) AS noproductivo,
timediff(m.hora_destino,m.hora_origen) AS productivo

FROM movimientos m JOIN movimientos n

ON m.usuario = n.usuario 
AND n.fecha_origen = m.fecha_origen 
AND n.id>m.id
```

Which works fine, but, the same query with an ORDER BY clause attached to it causes the database manager to crash and yield no result:

```
SELECT m.*,
timediff(n.hora_origen,m.hora_destino) AS noproductivo,
timediff(m.hora_destino,m.hora_origen) AS productivo

FROM movimientos m JOIN movimientos n

ON m.usuario = n.usuario 
AND n.fecha_origen = m.fecha_origen 
AND n.id>m.id

ORDER BY m.id
```

I need the database results to be ordered, leaving that out is not an option for the required task.

Comment: `Which works fine` ... no it doesn't.  Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes no sense.  Your second query is the real one.  Maybe it is crashing because the tables are too large.

Comment: Just a guess, but your `n.id > m.id` condition is probably causing an explosion of intermediate results; since you are trying to order by m.id after all that, it is not even known which n row which noproductivo was calculated from; given enough n matches, your ordered result would possible only even show one m.id value for all it's rows. _Also, your question title says GROUP BY, and you've tagged it as group-by; but your queries have no GROUP BY._

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why using **limit** w/o order by makes no sense? :> Then, right, mb table are big and it's taking a lot of time to reorder your stuff. Are you using indexes on columns which you are using to join?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just added the LIMIT to see a small sample of results when I was testing and i forgot to remove it. Thanks for pointing it out. Anyway if the case is that the tables are too large, is there any workaround?

Comment: Yes, we need to tune your query.  You might want to include the definitions for the two tables involved in the query.

Comment: @Uueerdo do you reckon i should remove the `n.id>m.id` then? According to the table defnition (which will upload asap) I can achieve the same result checking for `TIMEDIFF(n.horaorigen,m.horaorigen)`, since they are logs of the time at the moment and therefore would have differente values

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will be able to get my hands on the code tomorrow and I'll upload then, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I am not necessarily saying to remove `n.id>m.id`; but from your query and the information you've provided it is not clear what is supposed to be accomplished with this condition. In addition to table definitions, you should probably say how the tables relate to one another, and the purpose of this query.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks for answering, I have answered my own question explaining why I close it.

Comment: @WilsonHauck  Thanks for answering, I have answered my own question explaining why I close it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for answering, I have answered my own question explaining why I close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who answered and I'm sorry I couldn't answer before, I was told to forget about this particular query since our team is going to focus in creating a brand new DB since this one is built terribly. I have just arrived to this company less than a month ago and I found the DB and code like this, quite a mess. So we are going to start all over. Thanks for the answers anyway.

**Explanation:**

If anyone is curious about the problem, we found out the structure of the DB was poorly designed and then it forced us to create too complex queries, this is hte main reason we are discarding it.

Simply put, bad design meant really bad performance. We're deleting the work of the previous devs and starting from scratch.